# Problem with android library which support just armeabi and x86

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin, android-library, abi

I'm developing an app for my company and we are facing a problem. We have imported a library (no ours, we bought it) and it didn't work without setting the `abiFilters` to

```
ndk {
    abiFilters "armeabi", "x86"
}
```

that made the  library works but Salesforce SDK is bugged/not working with this filter. The library that we bought is an `.aar`, we unzipped it and found that libraries for `armeabiv7` and `x86_64` is not there.
There is any way to force the `.so` or whatever to search for `armeabi` and `x86` library JUST for that module without setting filter for the entire application?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: While it doesn't answer your question, you should be aware that starting August 1 2019, all new apps and updates to existing apps that contain 32-bit native libraries will be required to also contain 64-bit versions of those libraries. There are a couple of exceptions to this. See https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/01/get-your-apps-ready-for-64-bit.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There is any way to force the SO or whatever to search for armeabi and x86 library JUST for that module without setting filter for the entire application?

Answer is NO.

Because, on 64-bit devices, if you have provided both 32-bit and 64-bit `.so`, the system will pick the 64-bit version for **all** the `.so` libraries. If some a library does not have the corresponding 64-bit library, your app will throw error `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Library xxx not found`, this is because the system needs a **consistent AND non-mixed** native instruction sets, i.e. either pure 64-bit instructions or pure 32-bit instructions. You **CANNOT** expect that the Android system picks up 64-bit `.so` for some libraries but at the same expect it picks up 32-bit `.so` for other shared libraries.

For your case, the `abiFilters` actually forces all your `.so` files to only have 32-bit version `.so` for your final apk, so that your app can work like you said.

Answer (score 0):

You can pretend that the **armeabi** library is **armeabi-v7a**. If you can repackage the **.aar** file, simply move the so file to `jni/armeabi-v7a`. Alternatively, you can put the library to `app/src/main/jniLibs/armeabi-v7a`, and set

```
ndk {
  abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
}
```